# How to "combine" Persistent's SqlBackend with a custom monad?

Tags: haskell, yesod, monad-transformers, haskell-persistent

I have a custom monad stack for my Servant app, which I'd like to keep to a single `ReaderT` without making it an "onion" over `SqlPersistT` or suchlike. Problem is, I haven't been able to find any code samples that do this.

It seems like most Persistent functions return an action in the following monad: `(MonadIO m, PersistRecordBackend record backend) => ReaderT backend m record`

Here's the definition of `PersistRecordBackend`:

```
type PersistRecordBackend record backend = (PersistEntity record, PersistEntityBackend record ~ BaseBackend backend)
```

`BaseBackend` is part of the `HasPersistentBackend` type-class:

```
class HasPeristenBackend backend where
  type BaseBackend backend
  persistBackend :: backend -> BaseBackend backend
```

So, if I'm on the right track, either my custom `AppM` or `Env` will have to implement this `HasPersistentBackend` type-class.

```
data Env = Env {envDbPool, envLogger, envOtherStuff}
type AppM = ReaderT Env IO
```

Any help with getting this working would be appreciated. Finally, I'd like to be able to call `runSqlPool` directly in `AppM` (i.e. without any form of `lift`)